# is this signal command_signal in sensitivity list ignored in synthesis?

Tags: vhdl

the following process is part of my vhdl code. But I am not sure whether this works after synthesis.

Are **counter_sdin** and **command_signal** ignored during synthesis?

```
type state_type is (rst_state, command_state, data_state, delay_state);
signal next_state   : state_type;


process(reset_n_t2, counter_sdin, command_signal)
begin
    if reset_n_t2 = '0' then
        next_state <= rst_state;

        vbat_signal <= '0';
    elsif counter_sdin = 7 then
        -- State Machine
        case next_state is 
            when rst_state =>
                
                
                if rst_counter = 26d"450001" and command_signal = '1' then

                        rst_signal <= '0'; 
                        next_state <= command_state;

                else
                    
                    rst_signal <= '1'; 

                    next_state <= rst_state;    
                end if; 
                           
            when command_state =>
                
                
                if counter_rom = 8 then
                    delay_signal <= '1';

                    next_state <= delay_state;
                elsif counter_rom = 23 then
                    delay_signal <= '0';

                    next_state <= data_state;
                else
                    delay_signal <= '0';

                    next_state <= command_state;                            
                end if;
            when delay_state =>
                
                
                if delay_counter = 26d"1100001" and command_signal = '0' then
                    delay_signal <= '0'; 

                    next_state <= command_state;
                else
                    delay_signal <= '1'; 

                    next_state <= delay_state;    
                end if; 
            when data_state =>

                
                if counter_rom = 20 then
                    delay_signal <= '1';
 
                    next_state <= delay_state;
                    
                else
                    delay_signal <= '0'; 

                    vbat_signal <= '1';    
                end if;                                       
        end case;                       
    end if;
end process;
```

I have another question about the other snippet of the code. Should I put `code` in the sensitivity list.

```
  convert_scancode: process (edge_found,kb_data)  

  begin 
        
    if edge_found = '1' then
      
      code(9) <= kb_data;
      
      code(8) <= code(9);
      
      code(7) <= code(8);
      
      code(6) <= code(7);
      
      code(5) <= code(6);
      
      code(4) <= code(5);
      
      code(3) <= code(4);
      
      code(2) <= code(3);
      
      code(1) <= code(2);
      
      code(0) <= code(1);
      
      end if; 

  

  end process convert_scancode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have designed a combinatorial process, because you do not check at any clock edge.

At a combinatorial process synthesis assumes that all signals which a read are also element of the sensitivity list.
So command_signal and command_signal are not ignored, but checked and all other signals which are read are also added to the sensitivity list in synthesis.
These signals are added: next_state, rst_counter,  counter_rom, delay_counter.

So you will have different sensitivity lists in simulation and synthesis, which means your design after synthesis will behave different as your design in simulation.
The synthesis tool will probably give you warnings because of the missing signals in the sensitivity list.
So you must add all the signals to your sensitivity to have the same behavior in both cases (or use "all" in case of VHDL-2008).

But then you will have the problem that you change next_state in your process and next_state is also part of the sensitivity list.
So the process will forever be called immediately again after it has finished, so you will get no simulation progress in time.
This means it is a bug to have a signal in the sensitivity list which is changed inside a combinatorial process.
Perhaps you made a typo and in real you wanted to read the signal "state" instead of "next_state".

At last your process has the problem that you do not assign a value to the signals (for example vbat_signal) in all branches.
This will cause synthesis to insert a latch for these signals (to have a value at which the signal can be hold, when it is not assigned) which is a design style you should not use,
because it may create a lot of not resolvable timing problems at synthesis.
The simplest solution to this is assigning a default value to all your signals at process start.

Comment: DO you mean I should use `elsif rising_edge(clk)` instead of  `elsif counter_sdin = 7 then`

Comment: Are you sure `next_state` should be in sensitivity list? `next_state <= delay_state`, I would say `delay_state` and `command_state` should be put inside sensitivity list.

Comment: As there is "case next_state", next_state must be in the sensitivity list. delay_state and command_state are values, not signals, so they cannot be put into the sensitivity list. You are trying to build a FSM, have a look at [HDL-FSM-Editor](http://www.hdl-fsm-editor.de)

Comment: Please see the updated question. I have another question about the other snippet of the code. Should I put `code` in the sensitivity list `convert_scancode: process (edge_found,kb_data) `?

Comment: This process is a combinatorial process, as no clock edge is checked.
But as you do not assign a value to code when edge_found='0', you will get 10 latches for code.
I don't think that's what you intended, because latches are kind of bad solution for FPGAs/ASICs.
To answer your question: You must put code in the sensitivity list, because only then synthesis and simulation will behave identically.
But then you will see, that kb_data is propagated during edge_found='1' to all bits of code.
As code shall store a value you should put it into a process, which is sensitive to a clock edge.